Correct conditions for the image of a matrix to intersect a cone?
Given an $m \times n$ real (or rational) matrix $A = (a_{ij})$, what are necessary and sufficient conditions for the image of this matrix to intersect a cone? I am specifically interested in the cone $\{(y_1,...,y_m): 0 < y_i < \infty\}$.
One sufficient condition is that the rows of $A$ are linearly independent, as this would mean $A$ is surjective. A necessary condition is that the rows of $A$ are independent when the coefficients are all positive: if there exists $b_1,...,b_m \geq 0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}b_i = 0$ for every $1 \leq j \leq n$, then $b_1 = \cdots = b_m = 0$. My intuition also says this necessary condition is sufficient, but I cannot seem to prove this fact. Is it truly sufficient or is there a simple counterexample I am not seeing?

Sufficiency: By contradiction. The image of $A$ has codimension at least one and does not intersect the positive cone $\mathbb{R}{>0}^m$. By the Hahn-Banach separation theorem (fin.dim. version), there is a $b\ne 0$ such that $b^T A=0$ and $b^T x > 0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}{>0}^n$. The last condition is the same as $b\ge 0$, which is the desired contradiction.

I believe that does it. I'll expand this into an answer and close the question. Thanks!

To expand on the solution given by Igor, we prove the contrapositive. Suppose the image of $A$ (denoted $I(A)$ for convenience) does not intersect the positive cone $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^m$. Then applying the Hahn-Banach separation theorem to $\mathbb{R}^m$, $I(A)$ and $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^m$ are separated by a linear functional $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\sup_{x \in I(A)} f(x) < f(y)$ for every $y \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^m$. But because $I(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$, we have $f(I(A)) = \{0\}$. This means $f(y) > 0$ for every $y \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^m$.
As we are in $\mathbb{R}^m$, there exists $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that  $f(x) = \langle x,b\rangle$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Since $\langle y,b \rangle > 0$ for every $y \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^m$, the entries of $b$ are all nonnegative. But $\langle Az,b \rangle = \langle z,A^Tb\rangle = 0$ for every $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$, meaning $A^Tb = 0$. Writing $A = (a_{ij})$ and $b = (b_1,...,b_m)$, this exactly means $\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}b_i = 0$ for every $1 \leq j \leq n$. So the necessary condition is also sufficient.
